# How can I export a C# DataGridView to PDF using iTextSharp while **maintaining the custom currency formatting**?

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I'm trying to export a DataGridView with custom currency formatting to PDF using iTextSharp, the formatting shows up perfectly on the DataGrid when running the program but doesn't appear on the PDF once I save it.

Here is the DataGridView code (showing the currency formatting):

```
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

            if (t != null)
            {
                a.Fill(t);

                //Custom currency formatting
                var format =              (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
                format.CurrencySymbol = "R";

                dgvMiscEntries.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                dgvMiscEntries.ColumnCount = 2;
                 //Assign column headers manually

                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[0].Name = "Description";
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Description";
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Description";

                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[1].Name = "Rate";
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Rate";
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Rate";
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider =     format;
                dgvMiscEntries.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";


                // Render data onto grid
                dgvMiscEntries.DataSource = t;
            }
```

And here is the iTextSharp code:

```
            //Creating iTextSharp Misc Entries Table from the DataTable data
            PdfPTable miscTable = new PdfPTable(dgvMiscEntries.ColumnCount);
            miscTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
            float[] miscWidthPosit = new float[] { 1000f, 200f };
            miscTable.WidthPercentage = 80;
            miscTable.SetWidths(miscWidthPosit);
            miscTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            miscTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
            miscTable.SpacingBefore = 10;
            miscTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMiscEntries.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        miscTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have searched for similar questions here and on other sites but I haven't found any addressing this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the `Value` property takes the actual bound value which is used to provide the formatted text.

So instead of

```
miscTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
```

use [FormattedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
miscTable.AddCell(cell.FormattedValue.ToString());
```